# Is there a commonly agreed threshold at which a compound is considered "insoluble" or "soluble"?

Tags: solubility

I'm doing a literature review on solubility prediction and this is a bit of information that surprises me in its absence. The only information I've found is through Wikipedia with 0.1 g per 100 ml, but that source throws up a 403 Forbidden and seems to be a university's course notes.

Comment: When people are doing predictions, they tend to speak in terms of exact numbers and not to reduce those to a binary _“insoluble/soluble”_ thing.

Comment: I don’t think that there is a commonly accepted limit between *soluble* and *insoluble*